# How to remove prefixes and suffixes from filenames in a given directory?

Tags: files, scripting, filenames, rename

I have many files with the same prefix and the same suffix. I want to remove both from filenames. Both contain spaces.

So `foo bar XXX doo par.jpg`, `foo bar YY YY doo par.jpg` would become `XXX.jpg` and `YY YY.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With prename:

Setup:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ > "foo bar XXX doo par.jpg"; > "foo bar YY YY doo par.jpg"
```

Action:

```
$ rename -n 's/^foo bar //; s/ doo par(\.[^.]*)$/$1/'  *
  foo bar XXX doo par.jpg renamed as XXX.jpg
  foo bar YY YY doo par.jpg renamed as YY YY.jpg
```

(Remove the `-n` to have those moves actually performed)

Comment: @BinaryZebra `prename` should stand for perl rename. There are others, or so I hear.

Comment: Sorry, @PSkocik my bad.

Comment: Thank you - worked like a charm! The comment from BinaryZebra was way too much over my head, but yours are way simplier.

Comment: @BinaryZebra No problem. I usually do make a lot of typos, so I do appreciate edits.

Answer (score 3):

If the filename is in a variable, the canonical way to remove a preffix is:

```
removepre="foo bar "
filename="foo bar XXX doo par.jpg"
filename="${filename#"$removepre"}"
echo "$filename"
```

The problem with the suffix you present is that there is an extension that you want to preserve, so it becomes a bit longer:

```
removesuf=" doo par"
filename="foo bar XXX doo par.jpg"
extension="${filename##*.}"            ### store extension in a variable.
filename="${filename%.*}"              ### remove extension.
filename="${filename%"$removesuf"}"    ### remove suffix.
filename="$filename.$extension"        ### re-place the extension
echo "$filename"
```

All joined in one script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"

removepre="foo bar "
filename="${filename#"$removepre"}"

removesuf=" doo par"
extension="${filename##*.}"            ### store extension in a variable.
filename="${filename%.*}"              ### remove extension.
filename="${filename%"$removesuf"}"    ### remove suffix.
filename="$filename.$extension"        ### re-place the extension
echo "$filename"
```

Call the script as this:

```
$ ./script "foo bar XXX doo par.jpg"
XXX.jpg"
```

Understand that quotes are a must to process file names with spaces.